# Find method with no match error

Tags: vba, excel, find, match

I keep getting a *"Run-time error '91': Object Variable or With Block Variable not set*. I know the issue is the find method is not finding a match, but I can't seem to find how to fix the issue. I have tried the If Not xxx Is Nothing...but I then get another error.

```
Sub SetUpFormulas50450()

Dim cnt1 As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim lnRow As Long
Dim lnCol As Long
Dim lnCol1 As Long
Dim lnCol4 As Long
Dim lnRow1 As Long
Dim tempA As Long
Dim tempB As Long
Dim a As Long
Dim LR As Long

Set Sh1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Pivot")
Sh1.Select

lnRow = 5
lnCol = 2

cnt1 = Sh1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'Sh1.Cells(1, 10) = cnt1

lnCol1 = Sheet1.Cells(lnRow, 1).EntireRow.Find(What:="Grand Total", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False).Column
'Sh1.Cells(1, 11) = lnCol1

Sh1.Cells(cnt1, (lnCol1 + 2)).Formula = "=SUM(" & Range(Cells(6, (lnCol1 + 2)), Cells((cnt1 - 1), (lnCol1 + 2))).Address(False, False) & ")"

'Calculate Frt Pct of Sales
For i = 6 To cnt1
    tempA = Sh1.Cells(i, lnCol1).Value
    tempB = Sh1.Cells(i, (lnCol1 + 2)).Value
    If Sh1.Cells(i, (lnCol1 + 2)).Value = 0 Then Sh1.Cells(i, (lnCol1 + 3)).Value = 0 Else Sh1.Cells(i, (lnCol1 + 3)).Value = tempA / tempB
Next i

'Calculate Frt Pd in Fut Mos
For a = 2 To (lnCol1 - 2)
    For i = 6 To (cnt1 - 2)
        lnCol4 = Sheet1.Cells(lnRow, 1).EntireRow.Find(What:=Sh1.Cells(i, 1).Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False).Column
        Sh1.Cells(i, (lnCol1 + 4)).Formula = "=SUM(" & Range(Cells(i, (lnCol4 + 1)), Cells(i, (lnCol1 - 1))).Address(False, False) & ")"
    Next i
Next a
End Sub
```

I am having the issue at the line:

```
lnCol4 = Sheet1.Cells(lnRow, 1).EntireRow.Find(What:=Sh1.Cells(i, 1).Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False).Column
```

Comment: You need to test for `Nothing` after calling `Find`.  This exact question seriously gets asked here on a daily basis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dim f As Range '<-- declare a range to collect the result of 'Find()' method
For a = 2 To (lnCol1 - 2)
    For i = 6 To (cnt1 - 2)
        Set f = Sheet1.Cells(lnRow, 1).EntireRow.Find(What:=Sh1.Cells(i, 1).Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False) '<-- try setting f to the 'Find()' method result
        If Not f Is Nothing Then '<--| check for f to be a "real" range
            lnCol4 = f.Column
            Sh1.Cells(i, (lnCol1 + 4)).Formula = "=SUM(" & Range(Cells(i, (lnCol4 + 1)), Cells(i, (lnCol1 - 1))).Address(False, False) & ")"
        End If
    Next i
Next a
```

Comment: Thank you all! I was trying the suggestions from ALL the other questions posed. My issue was when I was testing for the nothing I didn't take the .column off at the end of the line. Once I did that and then set up the If statement worked like a charm!

Comment: you are welcome. you may then want to mark my answer as accepted. thank you